# Find by date by attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, find

I have calendar and events. How can I find events by day? Event have created_at attribute.
created_at have year, month, day. hour, minutes. How can I find only by day?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
day = "04" #i.e. 4th of the month
@users = User.where("strftime('%d', created_at)  = ?", day)
```

If you want to specify the month also then you can do this:

```
month = "06" # i.e. June
day = "04"
@users = User.where("strftime('%d', created_at)  = ? AND strftime('%m', created_at) = ?", day, month)
```

Although there probably is a better way to do this.

Comment: m, thank u. and how can I see only created_at dates from the Events.all?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, `Event.all.map { |event| event.created_at }`